# Verify that ipconfig was applied

Tags: c++, dhcp, wininet, wlanapi

I am currently developing a tool that automatically connects and authenticates users to certain wireless hotspots under given circumstances.
To test if the device is behind a captive portal i send a http request via wininet and check if it gets redirected (yes i am aware of NCSI but it does not work correctly in this case).

If i do that directly after i get the callback for a successfull wlan connection i receive error 12007 (name not resolved) which i assume is because of the ipconfig not being fully applied at that point. If i put in a Sleep() for 2-3 seconds i dont receive the error (since i have one of the faster devices in our hardware-lineup it might vary on other target devices).

Is there a way i can programmatically check if the config has been fully applied to the interface?

Target-OS is Windows 7

Retrying like Jon suggests is not really a feasable Option in this case since I have to enable a Hotspot registration Mode in the Firewall which closes again after a certain number of network operations which is why I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally for a situation like this, if you error is catchable, you would retry for a certain amount of time then give up (timeout) with the most recent error.  This is simpler and the same logic the OS would be implementing anyways

So, in this case I would:

```
For X(default 30) seconds at most {
  test if I can get a dns resolution
  delay 1 second
}
```

Comment: Hello Jon, Thanks for your reply. That is basically what I am currently doing. The Problem with this method is that I have to enable a Hotspot registration Mode in the Firewall which automatically closes again after a certain number of network operations which is why I am looking to avoid trying too often. Guess I should add that Info...

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly the easiest solution would be to do a DNS lookup, using a randomly generated name within a domain that you control. E.g. `79BF2DA7-EE45-4E11-89A4-45EEF2838003.guid.example.com`. This should of course fail, but it has to fail by returning a negative response from the DNS server. And that DNS server has to be reachable to return a negative response.